# How to factory reset without having google account verification(FRP) during setup?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

I bought Asus Phone last 5 months, and I bought new one today. I'm planning to give the old one into someone but before that, I wanted to factory reset the device to clear all my data but I'm gonna need to sign in my account during the setup after the reset.

how can I reset without needing to sign in my account to verify?

I have full access to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I reset without needing to sign in my account to verify?

Remove all of your Google accounts from Settings →  Accounts before initiating a reset. That's all you need to do. Alternatively, if your phone offers *OEM unlock* option unde Developer Settings, you can enable it as well. Both would work. You can disable the latter setting later after completing the setup wizard on the next-cum-first boot post reset.

Tested on Nexus 6 a week ago.

Source: my own answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202364/96277).